# How to make a direct deep link?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I want to link directly to [this](http://www.bilviden.dk/Energi-og-miljo/Hvor-langt-p%C3%A5-literen.aspx?Action=showVehicle&id=10) page from my website. However this doesn't work without going to [this](http://www.bilviden.dk/Energi-og-miljo/Hvor-langt-p%C3%A5-literen.aspx?action=ShowSearchForm&type=OldCar) page first, maybe because of some viewstate or similar. Is there any way I can make this possible/easy for my users, so I don't have to tell them: "Here is the link, but btw. you have to click this other link first, if you wanner avoid the error page"?

Comment: Check with the website if they allow deep linking, maybe they have a solution for you. Could very well be them preventing it.

Comment: @Uriil, if you have not visited the second link, then the first won't work. It will give you an application error page. Try clearing your browsers history if you don't believe me. I'm not very familiar with why this is, since I'm not doing asp.net programming (I'm a ruby on rails programmer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the page is using some data from a cookie in code-behind which, it does not find, hence the 'object reference error'.

Just clear your cache, load the first page and have a look at the cookies. There are no cookies. There is an exception 'application error'.

Now open up the second page in another instance of the browser and look at the cookies. You will now find that there are 4 cookies: `__utma`, `__utmb`, `__utmbc` and `__utmz`. At least one of these cookies is tracking some data which is used in a server-side code: like `utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)`.

Now close everything and open up the first page and look at the cookies. You'll find all these 4 cookies now which are available to this page. Hence, no error this time.

So, it seems that deep linking is not a problem here. Problem is usage of cookie data in code-behind which fails if there are no cookies. I think there is nothing much you can do. :(

Edit:

As an afterthought, what you can do is put the home page of that website in a hidden iframe of your page. So, by the time user clicks on your link, the home page would already have been loaded and cookies will be available. So, the linked page will not err.

Comment: The problem is still "deep linking", because the error is not happening on his page, but on a page he is linking to.

Comment: Yes Alexander. The page he is trying to link is at *bilviden.dk*. The error is also at that page. That website is erring at that page. Also, the cookies are scoped to *bilviden.dk*. That's why I said, it is not at his end and hence not in his control.

Comment: Thanks, the idea about the hidden iframe is great!